# Lightroom to export list of path-filenames of selected images for external processing

Tags: lightroom, filenames

In Lightroom 3.6 I am trying to produce (export) a list of selected files to be processed externally in another application. I do NOT want to export the images.

I am seeking a list that produces the full paths with file names of files selected in the filmstrip.

```
d:\IMAGES\2013\US\01-25 Omaha CAM-A\NK175312.NEF
```

I'd would assume a script in LUA could do, starting with something like this:

```
local activeCatalog = LrApplication.activeCatalog()
local filmstrip = activeCatalog.targetPhotos
```

But from here on I am lost.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Good question. What I found is an export plugin which creates a text file with information about all files exported. I then wrote a Python script that parses the file and does what I needed with them. It would be trivial simply also delete the dummy export since in your case you do not need it.

Comment: @Itai - Right, no export needed. What export plug-in did you use?

Comment: It appears to be called *List Exported Photos*. At least that is what it appears as in the Export dialog.

Answer (score 2):

A donationware plug-in called [LR/Transporter](http://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrtransporter.php?sec=main) can do this according to its [change log](http://www.photographers-toolbox.com/products/lrtransporter.php?sec=change):

> Version 4.24, 20th September 2011
>
> Added new tokens to retrieve the full path name of the original image
>   files (only available on Lightroom 3 or higher). Many of you have been
>   asking for this for years, but we've only just noticed that Lightroom
>   3 finally gives us access to it!

When no money is donated it can only process 5 photos at a time. When a donation is given to the developer this limit is removed.

If you decide to use this software these are the steps needed to obtain a list of full paths from a selection in Lightroom:

1. Download and install the LR/Transporter plug-in.
2. Open Lightroom and select the photos you want included in the list.
3. Go to `File -> Plug-in Extras -> Export Metadata using LR/Transporter...`.
4. Make sure the `For each image, create a companion file with suffix` is unchecked.
5. Go to the `Summary file` tab and check `Create a summary of all images`.
6. Pick a filename for the list.
7. In the middle text box enter the following text: `{originalPath}{tab}`.
8. You can add a header and a footer in the upper and lower text boxes respectively.
9. Pick a destination for your list and click OK.

This would be the basic steps to achieve what you want. There are probably more advanced functions in this plug-in but I didn't explore them.

I am not affiliated with this application.

Comment: Yes this plug-in works. But I'd rather use a simpler plug-in or even better a script. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've just downloaded and "donated" to this plugin. It is annoying that they are "requesting a donation" for the full functionality. I would have donated more. Otherwise it works as expected, thanks.